How to proof the chain rule of Kolmogorov Complexity?
I have recently been studying Kolmogorov Complexity, and while going through the Chain Rule section, I found a logical error in the proof of $K(x,y) \ge K(x) + K(y|x)$ on the Wikipedia page.
The proof first demonstrates that at least one of the following two inequalities must hold:
$$
\begin{cases}
K(x|k, l) \le k + O(1)\\
K(y|x,k,l) \le l + O(1)
\end{cases}
$$
where $k + l = K(x,y)$. It then argues that this proves the target inequality $K(x,y) \ge K(x) + K(y|x)$. However, this argument is not logically sound, as it only proves that at least one of the two inequalities holds, not both. The final result relies on both inequalities being true, so the logic does not follow.
Furthermore, in proving the first inequality, $K(x|k, l) \le k + O(1)$, the logic posits that if the number of subsets with a prefix of $x$ is greater than or equal to $2^{l}$, then this character set can be divided into no more than $2^k$ equivalence classes. Therefore, the target string $x$ can be found by traversing this set of equivalence classes, proving the first inequality. However, this is also logically flawed because having one equivalence class with a size greater than $2^l$ does not guarantee that every equivalence class has a size greater than $2^l$. Consequently, the number of equivalence classes may not be less than $2^k$, invalidating the premise and thus the proof of the inequality.
The third point is that the set $\{a,b\}$ used in the proof is obtained by requiring $K(a,b) = K(x,y)$. However, since Kolmogorov Complexity is incomputable, the construction of this set cannot be achieved programmatically and can only be provided as an external input parameter to the program. Therefore, the $O(1)$ in the above two inequalities is not actually a constant but a very large quantity related to $K(x,y)$, approximately $O(2^{K(x,y)})$. This invalidates the entire proof process.
So, what are your thoughts on the Chain Rule of Kolmogorov Complexity, especially the three issues I mentioned above? Are there any more detailed materials you can recommend? Thank you!

Just having 1 inequality is indeed not enough. We need following: if $L$ is number of times $x$ appears, we have the first inequality with $l = \lfloor \log L\rfloor$, and the second with $l = \lfloor \log L\rfloor + 1$.
Your second point the article actually gets right. There are at most $2^k$ different words that appear in at least $2^l$ different pairs, we can write down these words (if we know $l$ and $k$), and $x$ will be among them. We can skip all words that appear in less than $2^l$ pairs.
Third point in article is also correct. Given $K(x,y)$, we can enumerate all pairs that are produced by some program of this length. Neither search for $i$-th word that appear in at least $2^k$ pair, nor search for $j$-th word that is paired with $x$, requires deciding when we have enumerated all possible pairs.
I can recommend "Kolmogorov Complexity" by Shen, Uspensky, Vereschagin. Chain rule is theorem 21 there.

The first point of the proof is actually correct, just not clear enough perhaps. It also took we a while to understand it. The key is that it says 'for all':
"For the ≥ direction, it suffices to show that for all $k,l$ such that $k+l = K(x,y)$, we have that either
$K(x|k,l) ≤ k + O(1)$
or
$K(y|x,k,l) ≤ l + O(1)$."
To make it clearer, I used De Morgan's rule to invert the signs and to translate it into the following equivalent statement:
"For the ≥ direction, it suffices to show that there do not exist any $k,l$ such that $k+l = K(x,y)$ 
and 
$K(x|k,l) > k + O(1)$
and
$K(y|x,k,l) > l + O(1)$."
Now you have the logical conjunction you were looking for, which should make it easier to understand the proof.

That's not enough. For example, if we would have for $k < 0.9 K(x, y)$, $K(x | k, l) = 0.99 K(x, y)$, $K(y|x, k, l) = 0.05 K(x, y)$ and for $k \geq 0.9 K(x, y)$ we would have $K(x | k, l) = 0.05 K(x, y)$, $K(y|x,k,l)=0.99 K(x,y)$, then system (both original and your equivalent) would be fullfilled, however the main inequality would not.

@mihaild Ok, to clearer, maybe this correct proof should also have mentioned that the pair (x,y) is already fixed and thereby all complexities are fixed before you can try all possible pairs (k,l), which makes it correct.
And then fix the next pair (x,y) and try all possible pairs (k,l) again, and so forth.

$x$ and $y$ are globally fixed, we don't need to iterate over them. And my example shows that there is a function that satisfies written inequalities, but not theorem conclusion, you can't get conclusion just from the inequalities - we need to use additional properties of Kolmogorov complexity (that with low $k$ the second inequality is true, and with low $l$ the first is true).

@mihaild Oh ok, so they should have mentioned that K(k,l) = O(log(K(x,y))) and therefore K(x|k,l) cannot vary much for changing k,l since K(x| k,l ) = K(x| K(x,y) ) + O(log(K(x,y))) . But deriving this statement would require the chain rule itself. However, this would not be circular reasoning as the required chain rule would concern smaller x and y. So it should be proof based on induction from smaller to larger x and y.

I don't think induction will work here, as summing multuple $O$ increses constant. I believe we actually need to perform the original reasoning, but notice that actual number of $x$ appearances is something fixed.
